# Custom GPUImage filter: each pixel is the sum of pixels above it

Tags: ios, objective-c, glsl, gpuimage, bounding-box

I'm trying to create a GPUImage filter to determine the bounding box of an image. The process would require the following step: copying the image except for:

1. pixels on last row is black if at least one of the above pixels is not completely transparent
2. pixels on last line is black if at least one of the pixels on its left is not completely transparent
3. pixels on last line is black if it would be according to rule 1. or rule 2.

This would convert image A into image B:

[image]

How could I achieve this easily?

Answer (score -1):

GPUImage filters support write shader file for it. You need to write shader that doing provided algorithm. So basically you need to subclass from GPUImageFilter and write shader file. :)

Comment: Hi, thank you but my issue is I don't know enough about shaders to code them properly. I am would be looking for some help on this